# How to make div scroll horizontal when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have top mini navigation I want to scroll it horizontally. when someone scrolls vertically downward. so that they can view the overflowing text in the mini navigation.

Comment: please share the code snippet that you have done so far (by editing your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wheel event` on your element for example

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#parent-element');
element.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    element.scrollLeft += e.deltaY);
})
```